# SQL DELETE STATEMENT explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server

This request works:

There are two successive FROMs.
When I delete the first one, it doesn't work why?

```
DELETE FROM TableA
FROM TableA dim
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ColA
    FROM TableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT ColA
    FROM tableC

) A ON A.ColA= dim.ColA
WHERE A.ColA IS NULL
```

**EDIT** 
This one doesn't work which I was supposing was the correct one:

```
 DELETE 
    FROM TableA dim
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ColA
        FROM TableB
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT ColA
        FROM tableC

    ) A ON A.ColA= dim.ColA
    WHERE A.ColA IS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the statement that doesn't work and the error you're getting?

Comment: And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Syntax for multi-table `DELETE` statements varies across RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, et al.).  "doesn't work" is close to *useless* in describing the actual behavior that is observed. Is it an error message? Are no rows deleted? Are too many rows deleted? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Does it really work to have `ColA` first in an equal condition `ON A.ColA = ` and then in a NULL comparison `WHERE A.ColA IS NULL`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: that's the pattern for an anti-join. Notice that it's an outer join to the inline view A... the condition in the WHERE clause will eliminate rows that had a match, leaving rows from `dim` that don't have a matching row. (As to whether that works in a DELETE statement, that really depends on the RDBMS, what syntax is accepted and supported.)

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the table join. The SQL Engine needs to know which source to delete from, and the odd `FROM FROM` syntax accomplishes that.

The statement you have is functionally equivalent to this, which is exactly the same except I substituted the table alias for the first `FROM` clause:

```
DELETE dim
FROM TableA dim
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ColA
    FROM TableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT ColA
    FROM tableC

) A ON A.ColA= dim.ColA
WHERE A.ColA IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT  EXISTS` :

```
DELETE dim
FROM TableA dim
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB B WHERE B.ColA = DIM.ColA) OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableC C WHERE C.ColA = DIM.ColA);
```

Your delete statement has two `from` clauses which is not correct, it should have only one immediate after `delete` statement:

```
DELETE dim
FROM TableA dim LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT ColA
     FROM TableB
     UNION 
     SELECT ColA
     FROM tableC
    ) A 
    ON A.ColA= dim.ColA
WHERE A.ColA IS NULL;
```

Also, `DISTINCT` with `UNION ALL` is redundant here if you want `UNIQUE` entry then use `UNION` instead.

Comment: But that wasn't the question, was it?

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about two `FROM` - that is [allowed in the grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)